# Why does the shift operator seems to cycle 64 bits integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to work with **bit array data structure** in C++. It's simple curiosity, but how should I explain:

```
uint64_t a = 1;
uint64_t b = a << 1;

cout << (a == (a << 64)) << endl; // get 1
cout << (a == (b << 63)) << endl; // get 0
```

Seems like a << x is **cyclic** when `x >= 64`, but **pads with zeros** when `x < 64`. Am I wrong ?

If not, what is the explanation ? I thought 64bits integers were not naturally cyclical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [[expr.shift](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#1)]:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or **greater than or equal to the length in bits** of the promoted left operand.

Hence, this is undefined behavior:

```
uint64_t a = 1;
a << 64;
```

Comment: Can you address the other half of this question, the behavior of `(a << 1) << 63`?

Comment: @Robᵩ There's nothing to explain: this is perfectly expected. The spirit of the question as I understood it is: _why does shifting 1 by 64 bits in one operation is different from doing it in two?_

Answer (score 1):

As YSC explained, shifting *in one operation* of more than the type size is undefined behavior; this rule comes from the desire to map bit shift operators straight to machine code instructions, that have different behavior in such cases depending from the processor.

For example, on x86 the SHL instruction masks the shift amount with 63 (when operating on a 64 bit register), which is probably the reason why you see that `a<<64` remains 1 (as `64 & 63 == 0`, hence it's effectively a no-op).

Notice that this is just an instructional explanation that generally holds well for simple cases (typically, with optimizations disabled, or with optimizations enabled but shift amount unknown, so when the shift does map to the underlying platform shift opcode). When shifting constants with constants the compiler may propagate the values and perform arithmetic internally in higher precision, or, even in the general case, emit code that works in registers larger than your data type and truncate at the end (e.g. it would be legal to map a shift of an `uint32_t` to a full 64-bit register shift, although not particularly smart), thus giving different results in these out-of-spec cases. Remember: undefined behavior is undefined, you cannot really expect anything specific to happen.

On the other hand, doing the operation in two steps works as expected, because both operations are well-defined (they fill with zeroes on the right, throwing away the bits on the left).

Comment: This is a nice explanation of _why_ this has been chosen to be UB. +1